# Start web page and an new activity from the same class

Tags: android

I just want to open a URL when a button is pressed and also to open new activity, but only the new activity shows up.

```
public void rate (View v){
    AppLink= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    i=new Intent (this, Lev7Activity.class);
    startService(AppLink);
    startActivity(i);
    this.finish();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **startActivity** not startService for opening webpage

```
public void rate (View v){
    AppLink= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    i=new Intent (this, Lev7Activity.class);
    startActivity(AppLink);
    startActivity(i);
    this.finish();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used **startService** to start the browser's activity. **startService** can only be used to start a background task (class which extends Service).
If you want to start a new activity, use **startActivity** instead:

```
public void rate (View v){
    AppLink= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    i=new Intent (this, Lev7Activity.class);
    startActivity(AppLink);
    startActivity(i);
    this.finish();

}
```

Comment: If you tried it you will find that it wont work also